# Oracle Data Modeler - Constraint Already Exists

Tags: database, oracle, erd

I'm new to Oracle Data Modeler and trying to create an ER diagram for a hypothetical company where it can have many outlets (Outlet), with many departments (Department) and many staff members (Staff).

I chose the relationship `1:N` Relation Identifying in order to create a composite key for both department and staff. I chose to do this because each department ID is linked to an outlet ID, while staff members are linked to an outlet.

Perhaps this is the wrong relationship because when I engineer the diagram, then extract the code from the DDL file editor and run it, I get a few errors like this:

```
ALTER TABLE stock
    ADD CONSTRAINT stock_products_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY ( products_product_id )
        REFERENCES products ( product_id )
```

Error report

```
ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table
```

02275. 00000 -  "such a referential constraint already exists in the table"
*Cause:    Self-evident.
*Action:   Remove the extra constraint.

The action is pretty straight forward - I should remove the extra constraint  but that leads me to questioning why it's there in the first place, and does this indicate that my method is wrong?

The code to create the tables is below, along with my ER diagram. I think the relationship between the tables is causing the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE department (
    department_id           VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    outlet_outlet_id        VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    department_name         VARCHAR2(30),
    department_floor_area   INTEGER
);

ALTER TABLE department ADD CONSTRAINT department_pk PRIMARY KEY ( outlet_outlet_id,
                                                                  department_id );

CREATE TABLE outlet (
    outlet_id           VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    outlet_address      VARCHAR2(40),
    outlet_phone_no     INTEGER,
    outlet_size         INTEGER,
    outlet_floor_size   INTEGER
);

ALTER TABLE outlet ADD CONSTRAINT outlet_pk PRIMARY KEY ( outlet_id );

CREATE TABLE products (
    product_id                    VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    product_description           VARCHAR2(30),
    currently_supplied            BLOB,
    sales_category_sales_cat_id   VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    supplier_supplier_id          VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE products ADD CONSTRAINT products_pk PRIMARY KEY ( product_id );

CREATE TABLE sales_category (
    sales_cat_id                 VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    sales_category_description   VARCHAR2(30)
);

ALTER TABLE sales_category ADD CONSTRAINT sales_category_pk PRIMARY KEY ( sales_cat_id );

CREATE TABLE staff (
    staff_id            VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    outlet_outlet_id    VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    staff_name          VARCHAR2(30),
    staff_phone_no      INTEGER,
    staff_mgmt_status   BLOB
);

ALTER TABLE staff ADD CONSTRAINT staff_pk PRIMARY KEY ( outlet_outlet_id,
                                                        staff_id );

CREATE TABLE stock (
    products_product_id   VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    stock_id              VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    number_of_products    INTEGER,
    outlet_outlet_id      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE stock ADD CONSTRAINT stock_pk PRIMARY KEY ( products_product_id,
                                                        stock_id );

CREATE TABLE supplier (
    supplier_id        VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    supplier_name      VARCHAR2(40),
    supplier_address   VARCHAR2(40)
);

ALTER TABLE supplier ADD CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY ( supplier_id );

ALTER TABLE department
    ADD CONSTRAINT department_outlet_fk FOREIGN KEY ( outlet_outlet_id )
        REFERENCES outlet ( outlet_id );

ALTER TABLE products
    ADD CONSTRAINT products_sales_category_fk FOREIGN KEY ( sales_category_sales_cat_id )
        REFERENCES sales_category ( sales_cat_id );

ALTER TABLE products
    ADD CONSTRAINT products_supplier_fk FOREIGN KEY ( supplier_supplier_id )
        REFERENCES supplier ( supplier_id );

ALTER TABLE staff
    ADD CONSTRAINT staff_outlet_fk FOREIGN KEY ( outlet_outlet_id )
        REFERENCES outlet ( outlet_id );

ALTER TABLE stock
    ADD CONSTRAINT stock_outlet_fk FOREIGN KEY ( outlet_outlet_id )
        REFERENCES outlet ( outlet_id );

ALTER TABLE stock
    ADD CONSTRAINT stock_products_fk FOREIGN KEY ( products_product_id )
        REFERENCES products ( product_id );

ALTER TABLE department
    ADD CONSTRAINT department_outlet_fk FOREIGN KEY ( outlet_outlet_id )
        REFERENCES outlet ( outlet_id );

ALTER TABLE products
    ADD CONSTRAINT products_sales_category_fk FOREIGN KEY ( sales_category_sales_cat_id )
        REFERENCES sales_category ( sales_cat_id );

ALTER TABLE products
    ADD CONSTRAINT products_supplier_fk FOREIGN KEY ( supplier_supplier_id )
        REFERENCES supplier ( supplier_id );

ALTER TABLE staff
    ADD CONSTRAINT staff_outlet_fk FOREIGN KEY ( outlet_outlet_id )
        REFERENCES outlet ( outlet_id );

ALTER TABLE stock
    ADD CONSTRAINT stock_outlet_fk FOREIGN KEY ( outlet_outlet_id )
        REFERENCES outlet ( outlet_id );

ALTER TABLE stock
    ADD CONSTRAINT stock_products_fk FOREIGN KEY ( products_product_id )
        REFERENCES products ( product_id );
```

[image: ER Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's an issue with the way you're extracting the DDL from the model - you're getting this statement twice:

```
ALTER TABLE stock
    ADD CONSTRAINT stock_outlet_fk FOREIGN KEY ( outlet_outlet_id )
        REFERENCES outlet ( outlet_id );

...

ALTER TABLE stock
    ADD CONSTRAINT stock_outlet_fk FOREIGN KEY ( outlet_outlet_id )
        REFERENCES outlet ( outlet_id );
```

I would expect this to fail with that error when it gets to the 2nd copy of the statement.

Comment: I can see that the statement is there twice, but I still don't know why. When I create a relational model, then I just click generate DDL. Which is why I think it's something to do with the relation chosen for each table?

Answer (score 0):

Just try using "/" instead of ";". For me the semicolon was the issue.